# Flyway Repeatable migrations - not executed in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

In our Spring boot application, we have set a versioned migrations in the db.migrations resource folder

- V1_0__create_table.sql
- V1_1__apply_roles.sql
- R__create_stored_proc.sql

The versioned migrations(V1_0 and V1_1) are run/validated at application start-
up but the **repeatable migration (R__) does not seem to triggered at all**.

We have an afterMigrate.sql as well, which seems to be triggered.

Could someone help me understand the correct way to **trigger repeatable flyway** migrations in spring boot?

https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/repeatable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.x unfortunately ships with an ancient version of Flyway by default (3.x). Update to either Spring Boot 2.0 RC or simply the newest Flyway version (5.x). Note that if this is an existing app you must migrate to Flyway 4.2.0 first, in order for Flyway's schema history table to be automatically upgraded for you..

Comment: How do we do this?  We have existing users with 3.x flyway and want to get everyone to 5.x

Comment: @ Michael J Lawley you could override the version of flyway on your dependencies (pom.xml or build.gradle). Right now I am stuck with spring boot 1 and flyway 5.2.0 which says that Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "version_rank" violates not-null constraint. Because repeatable doesn't have any version in the name of the script.

Comment: I had to use 5.1.4 of flyway to get rid of my version_rank problem. And I advise to use R__001_create_stored_proc.sql. in case you want to order many repeatable script.